# What is remote desktop shortcut to fix auto scaling?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, remote-desktop

I am on a Windows 7 computer remote desktop into a Windows 10 computer. The Windows 10 desktop is not scaling to fit the window size like it did before. I know there is a shortcut way to change this, but I can't find it anywhere. Does anyone know of a way get this desktop to fit into the window size?

The <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Break</kbd> is great, but I like to move my window around so having it stuck in one place does not help me.

Comment: Your goal isn't really clear.  Why not just set the desired resolution in the options of the RDP shortcut you're using to connect to the Win10 machine?